# What is the magicka-draining voice in Labyrinthian?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was doing the quest "Staff of Magnus" in Labyrinthian, and I wonder whose is the ethereal, magicka-draining scary voice in that place? Is that the voice of Morokei, a Dragon Priest in the end? Or something else? I'm just interested in how the story of Skyrim explains that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the voice is that of Morokei.

The conversation gives you a bit of a background to the story with regards to Morokei and the person he fought with.

The mana draining is also from Morokei, but is a one time scripted event so it does not reoccur even if Morokei is still alive.